# Creating thousands of cache files (.js) vs one generator (.php)

Tags: javascript, php, amazon-s3, amazon-cloudfront

My ad network clients include a javascript file like this in their `<head>` tag.

`<script src="example.com/ads.php?user_id=10&ad_settings=2934"></script>`

The `ads.php` file generates the javascript for the page using their settings. This involves reading settings from the database and passing them into a json variable. This script is requested every time the page loads on ANY of my client sites (so it can really hit my server hard at peak times).

My idea is to create thousands of cache files, one for each ad setting, and upload them to a cloud service so my server is never hit. So users would change their url to:

`<script src="cloud.com/user_10_settings_2934.js"></script>`
`<script src="cloud.com/user_XX_settings_XXXXX.js"></script>`

And so forth. This would mean my server only had to generate settings once and then never be touched again. If the user changes their settings in my dashboard, I will overwrite the file on the cloud.

My only concern is that this would create thousands (or millions) of files on the cloud server and the space requirements would be huge. I am using Amazon S3 + Cloudfront. S3 alone costs about $30 per TB every month.

Is this a realistic solution or should I just get a stronger server?

Comment: Have you investigated caching the database results: http://php.net/manual/en/mysqlnd-qc.quickstart.caching.php memcached or similar?

Comment: Caching is a good solution for your problem but caching every result seems a bit overkill. Also, filesystems have their limits on the number/size of the files. As @mulquin said, database caching would be a better solution.

Comment: Yes, we do have a caching system in place using Memcached + Amazon Elasticache. It works very well, but you can only fit so much data into memory...